# Extract stored segment masks for a lot of images fast with python

Tags: python, multithreading, pyspark, multiprocessing, dask

I have a lot of high res images (~15k) on which I've run an instance segmentation model and extracted a few segment masks for each image (have only stored the outputs - the pixel classification values)

I want to run through each of my images and now store each of those specific parts of the image in separate files - I have written fairly vectorized code to do this using numpy.
My issue is that I have a lot of images and since they are very high res, even though my code is vectorized it takes quite a while per mask and there are a lot of masks present.
Whats the best way to speed this up? Approaches I've explored:

1.DASK - read through for a bit but I don't know much about it and not sure how much it will help when the time taking step is reading, processing and writing the image data.
2. Multithreading/Multiprocessing - Have read that the best approach here depends on whether the app is IO/CPU bound - not sure what to use since both IO operations as well as CPU processing seem to be an issue here.

Code basically looks like this -

```
import pandas as pd
data_folder = 'images/'
output_save_folder = 'saves'
def save_mask(row):
  #Some code here
  #save extracted mask at output_save_folder

mask_data = pd.DataFrame({'image_path':['foo.jpg','bar.jpg'],'masks':[[.1,.52,.31],[.73,.48,.92]],[[.12,.34,75]]})
#data looks like this ^

mask_data.apply(save_mask,axis=1)
```

I'm open to using any approach I can using Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally just used python's multiprocessing module with pool and it cut down time taken by a factor of the number of processes (number of processes is less than number of CPU cores present).
DASK took way too long to figure out with my requirements and lack of knowledge. Multiprocessing was very easy to figure out and use.

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

data_folder = 'images/'
output_save_folder = 'saves'
def save_mask(row):
  #Some code here
  #save extracted mask at output_save_folder

mask_data = pd.DataFrame({'image_path':['foo.jpg','bar.jpg'],'masks':[[.1,.52,.31],[.73,.48,.92]],[[.12,.34,75]]})
n_processes = 10
with mp.Pool(processes=n_processes) as pool:
    results = [pool.apply_async(data_df.apply, args=(visualise_masks,1)) for data_df in np.array_split(mask_data, n_processes)]
    results = [p.get() for p in results]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, need to wait a couple more hours to do so but will do after.